# Is it "apply to" a position or "apply for"?

Tags: idioms

Is it apply *to* a position or *for* a position? Is position here a place you apply "to" (if it is actually the place) or a reason, in which case it would be apply "for" (if it is the reason one)?

Comment: You can search online like DDG search or google search, or you can search this forum also. Please post the results of your research here. It may be that in the past similar questions may have been asked and answered in this forum itself.

Comment: You can apply glue to a position 2 inches from the edge.  Once you get good at that you can apply for a position doing just that.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence with a blank. You generally apply for a role, and apply to do something, but there are probably edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about job related applying.
You apply to a company for a position.
I'll rail some examples off for you.
I applied for the position of HR management at the firm.
I applied to 10 different workplaces.
I applied for 10 different positions.

Comment: rail off? What's that? You mean: reel off some examples...